# Django Rest Framework only display text - no css

Tags: django-rest-framework

I setup setup a local web server to run on our local network. Django Rest Framework displays correctly on my localhost but if i access it from a different computer on the LAN it only displays text - none of the css. I did a collectstatic - everything seems to be correct. I'm assuming this might be a relatively simple problem. :) Any ideas or suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you also configured the web server to serve the static pages.

Open a developer's tool on a browser and have a look at the response from the server for the CSS/JS files.

If you see a lot of 404 consult some documentation about how to serve static files (the STATIC_ROOT location in the settings) under the URL corresponding to STATIC_URL.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably exactly what it is, because it's not serving the CSS.  I thought I had in the conf. file - but I used webmin to administrate my apache servers... I don't know if that has anything to do with it. I'm new to using webmin...

Comment: The thing you need to realize is that static files should not be served by django itself. Django documentation show an Apache configuration file as example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: I'm using WSGI  and the static files are included in the apache conf file.  that's what's not making sense. they are working locally - but arent' being served if you access it from another computer on the LAN.

Comment: I assumed that by "working locally" you meant working with the run server. Can you confirm it works with the wsgi and static files on localhost ? How do you access your localhost then ? loopback or public ip ?

Comment: I got it working! :) Apparently when I had adjusted my directory structure it had created a second static directory and I didn't realize it at first. I had adjusted my apache conf file, but however django handles static files - added the static directory where it "would have been" before I made adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for a similar reason. If `DEBUG = False` in your settings.py file, DRF will also appear. Changed back to `DEBUG = True` and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If Your Editing In Pythonanywhere And Mentioned STATIC_ROOT And STATIC URL After That It Shows Without Style Use `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will store all the new static files in the STATIC_URL

Answer (score 0):

For people still struggling with this:
In your `commons.py` file add below lines:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static'))
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then do `python3 manage.py collectstatic`
Don't forget to add `static/` folder under `.gitignore`.
you can do this in your server anyway. doesn't need to go into git.